# VueJS return value from promise in method section of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The function below set the `this.personStatus` on all components `v-bind`. How can I make it update a single `comm-person` component or multiple `comm-person` components depending on the result of the `axios.post`?

The template extract for a person is this:

```
<comm-person
   v-for="person in people"
   v-show="(!pollActive) || isParticipant(person)"
   :participant="pollActive && isParticipant(person)"
   :status="personStatus"
   :key="person.id"
>
<div class="checkbox-wrap"><input :disabled="pollActive" :value="person" v-model="selectedPeople" type="checkbox"></div>
<div @click="togglePerson(person)" class="name">{{person.given_name}} {{person.family_name}}</div>
<div class="phone-number">{{person.phone}}</div>
</comm-person>
```

E.G: `:status="personStatus"`

```
data() {
    return {
        pollText: '',
        primaryButton: {
            border: `2px solid ${iiColor('ii-green')}`,
        },
        secondaryButton: {
            border: `2px solid ${iiColor('ii-grey')}`,
        },
        people: [],
        safeUsers: [],
        unsafeUsers: [],
        selectedPeople: [],
        polledPeople: [],
        pollActive: false,
        messages: [],
        msgType: 'SMS',
        personStatus: '?'
    };
},
..
..
methods: {
getStatus(person) {

        axios.post(`${config.iiApiUrl[process.env.NODE_ENV]}/person/find`, {
            id: person.id,
        }).then((resp) => {

            console.log('handle response...');
            console.log(resp.data.ref);

            if(resp.data.ref != null) {

              if (this.safeUsers.includes(resp.data.ref)) {
                  console.log('person is safe');
                  this.personStatus = 'safe';
              }
              if (this.unsafeUsers.includes(resp.data.ref)) {
                  console.log('problem with person');

                  this.personStatus = 'safe';
              }
            }
            else {
              return '?';
            }
        });
    },
}
```

But the `this.personStatus` from the `axios.post` call updates all the components. How can I make it update one or two depending on the result?

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `post` returns a promise and it is performed asynchronously. `getStatus` will return before the anonymous function you pass in to `post` will be called. It cannot return the string value. For the caller of `getStatus()` to get the value of the returned string, you must use `then()`. I suggest you research asynchronous programming and promises in javascript a bit further to understand callbacks and when they are run.

Secondly, you typically should not bind a prop to the result of a method/function. Props almost always should be bound to a data field or computed.

I suggest you change the post handler to set a data field and bind to that instead.

```
:status="personsStatus"

data: {
    return {
        person: ??, //i dont know where this comes from
        personStatus: 'unknown', //some default value. maybe '?'
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.loadStatus(this.somePerson);
},
methods: {
    loadStatus(person) {
        axios.post(...)
            .then((resp) => {
                //your more complex logic here, 
                //but instead of returning a string, 
                //set the personStatus field like the following:
                this.personStatus = 'safe';
            });
    }
}
```

This may require you to create a child component to do this work if you have multiple `person` instances.

Comment: I need to set it on the person. can i call you?

Comment: Thanks for the advice - i'm nearly there with getting it fixed.

Comment: how do i do this for multiple persons?

Comment: But in the case of multiple persons?

Comment: I suggest you create a new child component which takes a single person object as a prop and executes the request in the child component. The parent component would then have one or more instances of the child component, either through a v-for or by declaring multiple components.